# Anyone deployed outlook Add-In on Office365 desktop application?

Tags: office365, ms-office, outlook-addin, add-in, office-addins

We have successfully created ADD-IN for office365 and outlook2016.
Now I want to support the Office365 windows desktop application. 
I am not able to find an option to Manage Add-Ins in the desktop.
Does anybody have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Source:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/manage-deployment-of-add-ins?view=o365-worldwide

> Centralized Deployment is the recommended and most feature-rich way for most admins to deploy add-ins to users and groups within an organization.
>
> Centralized Deployment provides the following benefits:
>
> - A Global admin can assign an add-in directly to a user, to multiple
>     users via a group, or to everyone in the tenant.
> - When the relevant Office application starts, the add-in automatically
>     downloads for the user. If the add-in supports add-in commands, the
>     add-in automatically appears in the Ribbon within the Office
>     application.
> - Add-ins will no longer appear for users if the admin turns off or
>     deletes the add-in, or if the user is removed from Azure Active
>     Directory or from a group that the add-in is assigned to.

Before you begin, see Determine if Centralized Deployment of add-ins works for your Office 365 organization.

In the admin center, go to the Settings > Add-ins page.

Select Deploy Add-in at the top of the page. On the overview page, select Next.

Select an option and follow the instructions.

If you selected the option to add an add-in from the Office Store, you can now make your add-in selection. Notice that you can view available add-ins via categories of Suggested for you, Rating, or Name. Only free add-ins are available to add from the Office Store. Paid add-ins aren't supported currently. Once you've selected your add-in, you will need to agree to some additional terms and conditions in order to proceed.

On the next page, select Everyone, Specific users/groups or Just me to specify who the add-in is deployed to. Use the Search box to find the users or groups who you want to deploy the add-in to.
NOTE: Learn about the other states that apply to an add-in. See Add-in states later in this topic.

Select Deploy.

A green tick will appear when the add-in has been deployed. You can follow the on-page instructions to test that the add-in has deployed successfully.

Users may need to relaunch Office to see the add-in icon appear on the ribbon of app. Outlook add-ins can take up to 12 hours to appear on users' ribbons.

When finished, select Next. If you've deployed to just yourself, you can select Change who has access to add-in in order to deploy to more users.